# Как правильно инициализировать списки в объектах?

Tags: c#, json.net

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно инициализировать класс

**Приходит такой json:**

```
{
   "id":"*********-****-****-****-**********",
   "objects":[
      {
         "object":{
            "type":{
               "id":"*********-****-****-****-**********",
               "name":"test"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

**Инициализирую следующим образом:**

```
internal sealed class JsonModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<Objects> Objects { get; set; }

}
internal sealed class Objects
{
    public List<Object> Object { get; set; }

}
internal sealed class Object
{
    public List<type> type { get; set; }

}
internal sealed class type
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

}
```

**и получаю вот такую ошибку:**
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(json) =>

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestSocketIOv0._1.Object]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'objects[0].object.type', line 1, position 73."
```

Comment: `{}` - это объект (класс), а `[]` - массив. Внимание теперь на `"object":{` и `public List<Object> Object { get; set; }`, а также `"type":{` и `public List<type> type { get; set; }`

Comment: Но как это расписать не понимаю(

Comment: А как вы эти классы написали? Например, Id или Name у вас в виде свойств, вот и делайте Type и Object в виде свойств, а не коллекций. У вас же **один** объект, а не коллекция, почему вы везде пишете `List<>`?

Comment: internal sealed class Objects
    {
        public object Object { get; set; }
    }
Вот так? а как указать что в этом объекте есть "type"

Comment: А тип то зачем убрали?)

Comment: Минуточку, сейчас попробую)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ и вам спасибо, aepot дал подробную информацию=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При десереализации, если вы не планируете изменять списки, то лучше использовать массивы. Но дело конечно же не в этом, просто совет даю. Работать при сериализации оно будет и со списками, и с массивами одинаково.

Смотрите на квадратные скобочки, они у вас одни, значит и коллекция одна, а в модели у вас их целых 3. Еще старайтесь называть классы более понятно, а свойства с большой буквы.

```
internal sealed class JsonResponse
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ObjectContainer[] Objects { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class ObjectContainer
{
    public ObjectData Object { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class ObjectData
{
    public ObjectType Type { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class ObjectType
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Кстати, судя по звездочкам в JSON, у вас Id - это не `string`, а `GUID`. Попробуйте так:

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

Должно сработать.

Comment: А еще подскажите пожалуйста, как вызвать теперь name в коде?
json.Objects.Object.Name конечно же не работает =(

Comment: @Liana коллекция же `json.Objects[0].Object.Type.Name`.

Comment: Objects[0].Object.Type.Name* Спасибо большое, очень вручили.